# How to add fields in NEST elastic search nest Attribute mapping?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

```
 "properties": {
          "data": {
            "type": "text",
            "boost": 2,
            "fields": {
              "raw": {
                "type": "text"
              }
}
```

I need to add fields pragmatically, in above code i need to add data.raw. Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to add [multi_fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/multi-fields.html) with attribute mapping; For this, you'll need to use [fluent mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html)

```
void Main()
{
    var client = new ElasticClient();

    client.CreateIndex("index-name", c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Test>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Text(t => t
                        .Name(n => n.Data)
                        .Boost(2)
                        .Fields(ff => ff
                            .Text(tt => tt
                                .Name("raw")
                            )
                        )   
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );
}

public class Test
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```